# Magento: Reviews and ratings not showing in backend

Tags: magento, backend, rating, review

My version of Magento is 1.8.1.0. The problem is that I cannot see the "Reviews and Ratings" link under Catalog. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

I have recently upgraded from Magento 1.6.2 to 1.8.1.0.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` and see if `Mage_Review` is enabled there.  If it's not there at all, check that there's a `Mage_Review.xml` in `app/etc/modules`.

If it's enabled and still not showing, you may be missing some Adminhtml .xml files.

Comment: Thank you! Mage_Review was disabled indeed.